# is there any programming language that can bring together edit and compile / run?

Tags: programming-languages, coding-style, editing, inline-assembly

When I code, I always write little pieces of unit, and compile it often. This helps me to make sure that everything run correctly, but it's very time consumed. ***is there any programming language that can support us to do coding and running at the same time side by side ?*** i mean as soon as a key press leads to valid code, the effect of the edit is incorporated into the executing program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for, is sometimes called a lively system, incremental system or self-sustaining system (S³).

It's not really a property of the programming language, it's a poperty of the development environment. The only thing it *does* have to do with the programming language is that some programming language *communities* are violently opposed to the very idea of liveliness and thus those communities tend to not produce lively tools, while other communities cannot imagine life without a lively system, so they tend to produce them.

For example, almost all Smalltalk environments and many Lisp environments are lively, while I know of not a single lively C or C++ environment. There used to be a lively Java environment, called IBM Visual Age for Java (which was actually written in Smalltalk by IBM's Smalltalk division and based on IBM Visual for Smalltalk, so there's not really a surprise there), but when it was rewritten in Java as Visual Age for Java Micro Edition (which you probably know better under its current name, Eclipse), it lost its liveliness.

You ask about "coding and running at the same time side by side". Well, in a lively system, they aren't even "side by side", they are actually one and the same: there is no distinction between coding and running, there is no distinction between IDE and application, there is no distinction between compile time and run time.

The way you often develop software in Smalltalk, is that you simply write down what you want and run it:

```
aCalculator ← Calculator new.
aCalculator compute: '1 + 1'.
```

(BTW: "Run it" simply means writing that little snippet of code into *any* text area anywhere on the screen, highlight it and click "Run".)

[Note: left arrow is assignment (think `=`), upwards arrow is `return`. Original Smalltalk systems had them on the keyboard, modern systems typically use `:=` and `^` instead. Also, whitespace is message sending ("dot" in Java) and period terminates a sentence (`;`) in most languages. Arguments to methods are passed inline in the message itself after colons and not in parentheses.]

Of course, this doesn't work, because the `Calculator` class doesn't exist yet. So, the debugger pops up (did I mention there's no distinction between running and debugging?) and one of the options it offers you is to create that class. You don't restart the program, it just keeps on running. Now you get a *new* error, because the `compute:` method doesn't exist. Again, the debugger offers to create the method for you and you can directly enter the code right there: (Did I mention there's no distinction between the debugger and the editor?)

```
compute: aString
    ↑ 2.
```

The system has already filled the method name out for you and chosen a (somewhat) reasonable name for the method parameter. You only have to type the second line.

(BTW: if this workflow sounds familiar to you, it should. Kent Beck based the object model and execution model of his two testing frameworks (SUnit and JUnit), as well as the practices of Test-Driven Development and the Red-Green-Refactor cycle on exactly this workflow.)

Notice that at no time in the process did we stop or restart the running program. We were always editing the source code of the live system from within the system while the system was running. In fact, you actually *cannot* stop a Smalltalk program or Smalltalk system! Even if you shut down the Smalltalk system, what it actually does is serialize the entire state of the system (every class, every object, every variable, every thread, every window, even the position of the mouse pointer) to disk and when you start it up again, you are *exactly* where you left off. The system never stopped, it was just frozen. (If you are familiar with VMWare, Parallels, VirtualBox or something like that, it's like taking a snapshot of the VM. Or think of hibernating or suspending your computer.)

In fact, if you download a version of Squeak today, there's probably objects in there that have been literally running for 30 years. (This is another difference between Smalltalk and other systems. Smalltalkers believe that, just like fine wines, objects get better with age. This is in stark contrast to, for example, PHP or Ruby on Rails, where objects get thrown away pretty much after every web request.)

One of the most famous examples of this lively editing is from the pivotal "Apple Demo", when Steve Jobs, Jef Raskin and other members of the Lisa team visited Xerox PARC in 1979 to get a demo of the Smalltalk system:

> One of the best parts of the demo was when Steve Jobs said he didn't like the `blt`-style scrolling we were using and asked if we cold do it in a smooth continuous style. In less than a minute Dan [Ingalls] found the methods involved, made the (relatively major) changes and scrolling was now continuous! This shocked the visitors, espeicially the programmers among them, as they had never seen a really powerful incremental system before.—[The Early History Of Smalltalk by Alan Kay, HOPL-II, ©1993 ACM](http://Smalltalk.Org/smalltalk/TheEarlyHistoryOfSmalltalk_V.html#29)

Oh, and yes, you did read that right: Dan Ingalls rewrote the video driver in a live system, from within a live system, without ever rebooting the system or even pausing the application. In less than 60 seconds. (Did I mention there's no distinction between programming language and operating system?)

One of the best explanations of the liveliness properties can be found in the video [*Self; The Movie*](http://Smalltalk.Org.Br/movies/Self_big.mov) (Self is a derivative of Smalltalk). Also, take a look at the [*Lively Kernel*](http://Lively-Kernel.Org/) by Dan Ingalls (one of the original designers of Smalltalk), which is basically a port of the Smalltalk ideas to JavaScript, running inside a web page.

As I wrote above, this is really a feature of the environment, not the language. Thus, even though I used Smalltalk here as an example, you could implement a lively system for any language. I already mentioned Lisp as a language for which many lively environments exist and I gave an example for JavaScript. APL and Forth systems tend to be lively as well. [Factor](http://FactorCode.Org/) is a nice example of a lively system. The most extreme example might be the VxWorks real-time operating system which contains a semi-lively system for C(!), which has been used to diagnose and fix a priority inversion problem leading to spurious system resets on the Sojourner rover *on another friggin' planet!*

Comment: As always, your answer is interesting, thorough, and leaves a few doors open if we want to learn more. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> As soon as a key press leads to valid code, the effect of the edit is incorporated into the executing program?

As noted above, lots of languages offer an interactive read/edit/eval/print loop, but you are asking for something more.  The [Symbolics Lisp machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolics) of the 1980s offered functionality almost like what you describe; you did have to press one key to update the running system.  You could even replace a function without disturbing old activations of previous versions on the call stack.

The 1970s and 1980s were a golden age for interactive development environments, and since then, the field has languished.  Nowadays people think of Visual Studio as a highly interactive programming environment—and it is, but less dynamic.

I think the closest you could come today to replicating that kind of dynamic experience is [Squeak Smalltalk](http://www.squeak.org/), which has a sophisticated IDE based very closely on the Smalltalk-80 environment build at Xerox PARC (and by the same people).

Answer (score 3):

LISP, Scheme, Haskell, Perl, Python, Ruby, Maple, Mathematica, MATLAB, etc. Most interpreted languages can do this. Your code is interpreted and run as soon as you finish typing it.

Heck, even command shell counts, really.

Quote from [Wikipedia: Command line interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line_interpreter):

> Although most users think of the shell as an interactive command interpreter, it is really a programming language in which each statement runs a command. Because it must satisfy both the interactive and programming aspects of command execution, it is a strange language, shaped as much by history as by design.
>
> – Brian Kernighan & Rob Pike

---

For a video demo, watch [Conway's Game of Life in APL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9xAKttWgP4).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's necessarily a matter of language as it is a matter of IDE and such. Even compiled languages like C have interpreters for them.

You can probably find an interpreter for whatever you are programming in if you think it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

[Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) allows you to modify a running a program, essentially being able to update methods on the fly while the program is never stopped running.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm working on somethink like this on a hobby spare time project. It's using a static typed compiled language named Eiffel.

The difference to traditional compilers is that the compiler works as a server and not a command line program. It keeps all data parsed in memory and really does an incremental compilation on them. Together with an all in memory incremental linker the idea is to have
a compile/link/run cycle of less then 2 seconds.

But yes there is still a problem you can only solve with image based languages like Lisp or Smalltalk. That the code always starts with Adam&Eve and has to make its way up to a defined situation in your program.

But currently this seems to be the best compromise if you need a really fast executable language. The livelyness requires that a lot of performance is wasted cause existing object structures must be preserved in some way, Theoretically it is possible but the implementation is very complex.

Comment: That's basically how Smalltalk Environments work (minus the image, of course, but that is orthogonal), and Eclipse, being derived from a Smalltalk IDE, inherits this feature. However, in Eclipse this resident online compiler is only used for IDE features such as semantic highlighting, code navigation, early error checking, static analysis, intelligent code completion and refactoring. The *actual* build is not done by Eclipse's compiler but by the compiler of the JDK. Actually, that's how most modern IDEs work, and it's also why modern compilers are designed with that use case in mind.

Comment: For example, the Scala compiler, Clang and the Roslyn rewrite of Microsoft's Visual C# compiler all have online capabilities. The Scala compiler even has a special mode, specifically designed for IDEs.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, do you *really* want something like this?!

Let's imagine you have such a system set up for your C language environment. So, your editor is configured so that at every keypress it checks if it "leads to valid code"... how? Unless your editor redundantly incorporates all the same logic as the compiler/interpreter in parsing the code, you'll have to invoke the compiler. (Let's ignore the overhead of saving the file to disk and imagine your compiler can directly read the contents of your editor's buffer.) So at every keypress it compiles the code. You're probably going to get errors 99% of the time, just because you've haven't completed typing the name of a variable or keyword. How will your system know whether the error is due to that or due to a "real" error?

Also, how would you incorporate edits into a program while it is executing? Suppose your program is at a point five stack frames deep and you change the value of a variable that gets passed to the first function. There's no way to magically propagate the changes without starting execution at that first function again. But if the change isn't propagated, was it really incorporated into the program? Of course a debugger will let you modify existing variables in an executing program, but you can't do things like create new variables or function calls or control structures, all things which you might do under your scheme.

Most intepreted languages have a Read-Evaluate-Print Loop (REPL) where you can define functions which are then stored in the interpreter's environment, and you can call those functions by name, and even redefine the functions such that previously defined functions that call them will then execute the new versions. But even in this case, your program is not executing  any time you have a prompt and are thus able to give it something new to interpret.

Comment: The new visual studio actually does a compile/parsecheck in the background with every keystroke you type, letting you show compile errors before you compile ;^)

Comment: Thanks, reinier, for the information. I figure there probably was something out there that actually did all these things I said were impossible or impractical; I was vaguely aware of Erlang as you answered below.

So will the next version of MSVC show compile errors before typing anything at all?

Comment: richter: I'm not suggesting Visual studio includes a REPL for c# or c++ (although for f# it is included). I'm just suggesting that compiling at every keystroke is something which does happen nowadays. For showing compile errors before we type them we'll have to wait for the quantum computers ;^)